# meaning of the phrase "in a sure sign of something"?

Tags: meaning

Here is the context:

> Culinary cultural fusion is all the rage; more novels translated from languages then ever before, although few are read, and **in the surest sign of** cultural globalization, football, the world's game, finally has reached America.

Actually I cannot get the grammar of the phrase. Why did the speaker use the preposition *in* with it? Wouldn't it make sense without it? If it would not, then could you please explain what the difference is with *in* and without?